How in MAUI if I have two different Content Pages I can load first in second
CP - Content Page
For example:
MainWindow.xaml.cs - CP
MobileWindow.xaml.cs - CP
DesktopWindow.xaml.cs - CP
And I want If I have IOS or Android in MainWindow.xaml.cs load MobileWindow.xaml.cs
If desktop->load Desktop.xaml.cs
Help me please,) MainWindow.xaml.cs can inherits from other class. Give me best solution. But MainWindow.xaml.cs must be replaced by own by CP.
If you can use in xaml OnPlatform please)

You can't nest ContentPage.  You can place a ContentView in a ContentPage

@Maksym, for that request, add the code to your question (even if not correct) so we can advise you, at least the code shows how do you call/load MobileWindow.xaml.cs or DesktopWindow.xaml.cs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found solution:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MegaProj"
       xmlns:Desktop="clr-namespace:MegaProj.Views.MainPageView.Desktop"
       xmlns:Mobile="clr-namespace:MegaProj.Views.MainPageView.Mobile"
       xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MegaProj.ViewModel"
       xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:MegaProj.Convertors"
       x:Class="MegaProj.Views.MainPage.MainPageView">

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DesktopTemplate">
                <Desktop:MainPageDesktopView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MobileTemplate">
                <Mobile:MainPageMobileView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <ShellContent>
        <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="DataTemplate">
                <On Platform="WinUI, MacCatalyst" Value="{StaticResource DesktopTemplate}" />
                <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="{StaticResource MobileTemplate}" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
    </ShellContent>

</Shell>



WHERE <Desktop:MainPageDesktopView />,  <Mobile:MainPageMobileView /> -  Content Pages

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
